# Hook not working in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-hooks

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 */
/**
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 */
function glue_page_alter(&$page) {
    $page['content']['bartik.content']['content']['#markup'] = 'Hello Content!';
}
```

What wrong with this hook? It wont run (8.4.3). I've cleared the cache too

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, hook_page_alter was a convenient way to go when we needed to modify page elements that were added by other modules. Drupal 8 does away with this hook - hopefully for the better. To fill the void created by hook_page_alter’s dismissal, the following hooks have been introduced.

```
hook_page_attachments()
hook_page_attachments_alter()
hook_page_top()
hook_page_bottom()
hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()
hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()
```

Source: https://cryptic.zone/blog/where-hook_page_alter-drupal-8

Comment: Do you know any hook that runs when any new content is added in drupal  8.4.3? Like new article,page.

Comment: hook_node_presave or hook_entity_presave

Comment: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/8

Comment: thanks a lot, from _node_presave

possible to set response headers?

Comment: I know that i can do it via events in drupal 8, but for some reason need to add header in this function.